# Seeking QGIS user interface tutorials and web resources

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, references

I wish to familiarize myself with the capabilities of QGIS up to and beyond QGIS version 3.0.

Can you recommend some good web resources and tutorials that would show me QGIS' capabilities?

I am interested in both using QGIS through its GUI and in developing applications using QGIS.

Answer (score 61):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

**For QGIS 3.x users**:

- [QGIS User Manual](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html#testing) - includes both 2.x and 3.x documentation and links to many of the resources listed here
- [GIS SE's self-assembling FAQ on QGIS 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.0+-pyqgis?sort=frequent)
- [QGIS Planet](http://qgis.org/planet/) blog for more technical and development stuff.

**For QGIS 3.x developers**:

- [GIS SE's self-assembling FAQ on PyQGIS in QGIS 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis+qgis-3.0?sort=frequent)

---

**For QGIS 2.x users**:

- [QGIS Training Manual](http://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/) ... covers a wide range of topics
- [QGIS User Manual](http://docs.qgis.org)
- [QGIS Tutorials and Tips](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/)
- [Learning QGIS](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/learning-qgis-third-edition) ... if you already know GIS concepts and you are looking for a resource to quickly get started using QGIS
- [QGIS Map Design](https://locatepress.com/qmd) ... for tutorials on making maps
- [A Gentle Introduction to GIS Brought to you with Quantum GIS, a Free and Open Source Software GIS Application for everyone; by T. Sutton, O. Dassau, M. Sutton](http://www.edugis.pl/dokumenty/AGentleIntroductionToGIS.pdf) - 115 page manual for beginners with video lectures [here][49]
- [Desktop GIS: Mapping the Planet with Open Source Tools](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/gsdgis/desktop-gis) by Gary E. Sherman
- [QGIS Workshop](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/) from Harvard University
- [Tutorial: QGIS basics for Journalists](https://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/qgis-basics-journalists/) from UC Berkeley
- [Introducing GIS worksheets](http://linfiniti.com/dla/)

**For QGIS 2.x developers**:

- [General API documentation](http://www.qgis.org/api/)
- [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/) ... on developing python plugins
- [My own notes on developing Python plugins](http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/plugin-development/)

Answer (score 5):

QGIS is a project in constant development.  Partial tutorials are available at [spatialthoughts.com](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/).

For offline browsing or download availability you can look into the answers on the [Super User website](https://superuser.com/questions/139269/download-or-print-an-entire-website-as-pdf) (which is part of the Stack Exchange network). Try searching for Firefox/Chrome plugins using "offline browsing" from within your browser plugin search facility. It might help you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

For QGis C++ development there is little information, but still here is what I've found:

-[Official API doc](http://qgis.org/api/)

-[GitHub code example](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples) (pretty old, 2008, if I'm not mistaken it's for QGis 1.8 and earlier versions)

-[Coding Compilation guide](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.6.0_coding-compilation_guide_en.pdf) (pretty old too. For Qgis 1.6, called before Quantum Gis)

-[QGis C++ plugin development examples](https://github.com/thebigspoon/qgis_cpp_plugin_cookbook)

Answer (score 4):

a bit advanced: [Programming and QGIS](http://snorf.net/)

general:

[QGIS-SEXTANTE cookbook](http://qgissextante.blogspot.fr/)

[QGIS Tutorials and Tips](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/index.html)

This one is better suited for beginners:
[QGIS 2.0 WORKSHOP](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/)

Great resource for developing plugins:
[QGIS Workshop](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

A very good source is [locate Press](http://www.locatepress.com/books). The company specialized in books about the Qgis and GIS. It has some titles that have come out and some that are under publication and of course all is printed and e-book. The book of locate Press is:

- The Geospatial Desktop Open Source GIS and Mapping The QGIS Training
- Manual A Comprehensive Introduction to Quantum GIS
- Geospatial Power Tools Open Source GDAL / OGR Command Line Utilities
- The PyQGIS Programmer's Guide Extending QGIS with Python

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find nice video tutorials (and they are quite up to date)

http://foss4geo.wordpress.com/

The topics are:

- Introduction to geospatial technology
- Spatial analysis
- Data management,
- Cartography
- Remote sensing

Answer (score 3):

Ahh I remember when I first started trying to learn python scripts for QGIS almost a year ago (and I'm still quite bad at it!). The documentation I followed to some extent was the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/) which offers help in such things as describing how to do simple tasks through the Python Console rather than through interface.

Another huge help I found was in an obsolete feature of the latest [Processing plugins](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/), (*version 2.2.0-2* had this feature which can still be downloaded) which allowed users to use the graphical modeler and be able to export the model as a Python Script. This gets you familiar with calling the vast array of tools and the parameters they require.

Finally, there's plenty of questions asked here in [GIS:SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) which involve python scripts. This in itself is a massive learning resource not only for reading other posts but you can also ask for help from wonderful experts (not me!).

Answer (score 3):

I needed to review QGIS for its potential on a project. I found the few books available to be quite useful for getting started on the software. As with any book it will fall behind the software updates, but the core doesn't change that much. I was more interested in PyQGIS (e.g. QGIS Python Programming Cookbook), but there are also some for the software itself.

The ones from Packt publishing are generally decent, and 'reasonably' priced. I was usually able to access the ebook version from my local university's library.

See for example:

https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/qgis-example
https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-qgis-20
https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mastering-qgis

Answer (score 2):

I have a number of resources on my site [gis-university.com](http://gis-university.com/)

Some resources are free and others paid.

Answer (score 1):

you can find lots of information about python using in [qgis blog](http://blog.qgis.org/node/59) and [Python QGIS Cookbook](http://linfiniti.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/PyQGIS.pdf) - Pdf Book which have written by Martin Dobias (QGIS hacker who brought you many nice things including new symbology, python bindings, new labelling tool and the upcoming multi-threading renderer implementation --- from http://linfiniti.com) may help you for improving python skills for qgis...

Answer (score 1):

I started with this recently. It might be outdated slightly in terms of the version it was wrote around but it explains all the basics in a simple yet comprehensive manner.

It will allow you to start producing maps immediately.

Link - [QGIS Training Manuel](http://manual.linfiniti.com/LinfinitiQGISTrainingManual-en.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of digging into Python too, and had bookmarked [this page](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) as a starting point. The Python QGIS Cookbook looks great too!

Answer (score 0):

Check this site:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/

and also this playlist:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7HotvlLKHCs9nD1fFUjSOsZrsnctyV2R

documentation is always a good choice:

https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html