# Seeking resources for python scripting in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QGIS tutorials and resources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/qgis-tutorials-and-resources)

I would like to know regarding the available resources for starting to learn about python scripting for QGIS.