# How to export highlighted features from attribute table to an excel file?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv

When i selected some portion of the map in QGIS, in the attribute table the selected features gets highlighted...

How to export the highlighted features from attribute table to an excel file automatically..?

Comment: working on similar thing at my end. I am trying to make python tool as per the requirement. I think python script will be best option for you..

Answer (score 13):

Simply select the features on the map and use copy-paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ,    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) to copy the data into a text editor or Excel.

Comment: Great! Didn't know that before :-)

Answer (score 11):

Or:
After you highlighted them->right click on the Layer->Save Selction as->In the Drop-down menu you can choose csv(comma seperated value/ excel) format there. Done

Comment: Thank u for u r answer..........But my need is to automatically save the selected features as an excel file/csv file with out manual saving......U have any solution for that?

Comment: I see...I m afraid I have no answer for that.
The methods above are pretty fast and require only some seconds.So I m wondering myself, how it may work faster. Let me know,if you find out somehow...

Comment: Can i find the code for QGIS attribute table in python or in C++?If possible pls post the code or the link?

Comment: I m not familiar with python yet, but maybe you ll find smth here?
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/qgis-python-code-library-documenation

Answer (score 3):

Another easy solution might be the use of the "mmqgis" plugin. You can find it directly via the plugin downloader.

After loading you will find in the menu Plugins->mmqgis->Transfer a clickable dialog to export shape attribute tables to csv data. You can even export whole geometries.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the features, go to the attribute table then highlight the selected features that you want from that selection and then right click in the attribute table and hit "re-select highlighted" giving you your new selection which you can now export and save.

Hope that is clear/helps

Comment: i guess that is in ArcGIS...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I hope you will be OK about us pointing out that this appears to be an ArcGIS for Desktop answer to a QGIS question which is something you may see voted down.  I am hoping that no one will downvote in this instance but to avoid any chance of that you should be able to just delete your answer.