# Adjusting attribute table view column width using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, dimensions, width

I'm programmatically opening the Attribute table via Python through a plugin. All of the columns have a default width, but some of the data that I'm using do not fit.

[image: Default column width]

It's not enough to be able to click the column separator to make the column re-size to fit the data as there are several columns and several layers.

Can I, through Python, change this in any way, or is my only option to create my own table in Qt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableView

# Get a list of all open attribute table dialogs
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable' ]
# Set the column width for the first column in the first dialog to 200
attrTables[0].findChildren(QTableView)[0].setColumnWidth( 0, 200 )
# or instead set the width to match the contents maximum size
# attrTables[0].findChildren(QTableView)[0].resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Comment: I let the plugin run its course (loading all the layers) then, in the Python Console, I import `PyQt4.QtGui` and iface from `qgis.utils`. Fetch the current layer with `cl = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()`. Check that it's the right layer with `cl.name()`. Open the attribute table with `iface.showAttributeTable(cl)`, which is showing me the attribute table in the map window. Run the `at = [d for d in QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog']`, which return a list. This list however is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Listing the object names of `at = [d for d in QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets()]` i.e., without the condition for attribute tables there are around 90 objects but none are attribute tables.

Comment: Maybe there is the object name "AttributeTable" in `[d.objectName() for d in QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets()]`?

Comment: Yes. I was digging around using Python introspection [Seen here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/qgis-python-code-library-documenation/23230#23230) and found that I could use `QApplication.instance().allWidgets()` to search for `u'AttributeTable'` With this I could use the 1st code tip I got. I.e., problem solved.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the possible variations of the objectName. Please accept the answer, for reference for future readers.

Comment: I found out how to resize all the columns in the attribute table to their contents. Using `attrTables[0].findChildren(QTableView)[0].resizeColumnsToContents()`. Introspection is _very_ helpful. @Matthias I'm unable to use the `topLevelWidgets()` to find the `AttributeTable`. It gives nothing. Perhaps you should include in the updated answer that one should use `allWidgets()`.

Comment: Sure, I inserted the `resizeColumnsToContents()` as well. Just to know why the other method didn't work for you: Do you show the attribute table as a dockable dialog?

Comment: Yes, I do show the attribute table as a dockable dialog. Ah, I get it now. When it's not docked it will show up in the `topLevelWidgets()`.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Found your useful answer when searching how to get open attribute tables. May be there should be a QgsVectorLayer method for this?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Just tried this in QGIS 3.34 and failed... Is there an approach for new QGIS Versions?