# Adjust attribute table cell height

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2.14

I'm wondering if it is possible to adjust the cell height of the attribute table (QGIS 2.14.3). I would like to reduce the cell height, to avoid the unused space in a cell.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can type the following in the **Python Console** to set the row height for each row in your *Attribute Table*:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableView
layer = iface.activeLayer()
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable' ]

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrTables[0].findChildren(QTableView)[0].setRowHeight(feat.id(), 20)
```

---

Note: it seems that the height is **not saved** as when you close and reopen the attribute table, the cell height is returned to its default value. The columns width however are saved.

---

Credit to [@MatthiasKuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn) for his [answer to this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91451/how-to-adjust-qgis-attribute-table-view-column-width-using-python/91453#91453).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joseph! I was hoping that there is a permanent solution for this.

Comment: @Martin - Most welcome! Hopefully there is in which case someone can post a final solution =)

Comment: I think that it's not implemented yet. I found [this](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13903) feature request, it should refer to your issue.

Comment: @mgri - Great find! I should certainly think it does refer to this issue. Many thanks :)

Comment: @mgri Jep it seems like that this refers to the issue. I hope that they will fix it in an upcomming version

Comment: Are there a good solution for QGIS 3.16 ?

Comment: **Related :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259923/pyqt5-cannot-import-name-qapplication