# Autosizing all fields in a QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-3

Is there a way to autosize all fields in an attribute table?

I am working with attribute tables that have over 50 columns and all of them have long names. Instead of autosizing single columns via double-click or right-click...

[image]

... I'd rather resize them all at once.

I'd be interested in doing this manually, but a script will do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to achieve this manually, probably a good idea to submit a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis).

Based on the answer from this post: [How to adjust QGIS attribute table view column width using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91451/how-to-adjust-qgis-attribute-table-view-column-width-using-python), you could write a script to resize the column width of all loaded attribute tables to fit its contents:

```
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']

for x in attrTables:
    x.findChildren(QTableView)[0].resizeColumnsToContents()
```

---

As mentioned by [@BritishSteel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23263/britishsteel) in the comment, the above code is for attribute tables opened as a **dock window**. If the attribute table is either a dock window **or a dialog window**, the following could be used:

```
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable' or d.objectName().startswith('QgsAttributeTableDialog')]

for x in attrTables:
    x.findChildren(QTableView)[0].resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Comment: Hmm, in QGIS 3 the *attrTables* list is empty.

Comment: OK, the widget is not called AttributeTable but *QgsAttributeTableDialog/nameofatable*... so the above list comprehension can be adjusted as follows: attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName().startswith('QgsAttributeTableDialog')]

Comment: @BritishSteel - Thanks, I forget I always have the dock window option checked as default. Edited post :)