# Zooming from python console of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

What are the commands to apply all types of zoom (full, on selected layer, etc.) in python console?
I'm searching both on pyqgis cookbook and API documentantion, but I'm not finding anything interesting.

Comment: Not sure please check out http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/canvas.html#embedding-map-canvas & QGIS API doc (http://www.qgis.org/api/index.html)

Comment: + useful for you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/where-can-i-find-qgis-tutorials-and-resources

Answer (score 19):

After getting around cookbook, the best place to learn is referring the [QGis API Documentation](http://www.qgis.org/api/). In this case we are looking for zoom functions, which are related to map canvas. So check if `QgsMapCanvas` class contains something.

[image]

Zoom functions available in QGis are provided in [QgsMapCanvas Class](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html).

```
>>> canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
>>> canvas.zoomIn()
>>> canvas.zoomOut()
>>> canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
```

Comment: How to you get to `qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()` from `QgsMapCanvas`? I tried to to `a = QgsMapCanvas()` and then `a.zoomIn()` but it doesnt do anything. Thanks

Comment: You can just use `iface.mapCanvas()`.

Answer (score 6):

All the zoom options under the 'View' menu can be executed in the python console by the following code.

```
eMenu = self.iface.viewMenu()
eMenu.actions() [index].trigger()
```

Replace the "*index*" with the index number of the zoom action you want to perform. For eg., To perform 'zoom to selected features', use

```
eMenu.actions() [12].trigger()
```

Comment: How do you know that the number 12 denotes 'zoom to selected features'?

Comment: You better use `iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()` instead!