# Centering map on maximum value of raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, zoom, pixel, maximum

I have a very large QGIS raster layer showing the differences between two nearly identical rasters.

Because of this, it is very difficult to find where in this layer the few pixels that are different occur.

I have thought that one way to find them might be to have QGIS zoom in and center on the maximum point of the layer. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For python code hints, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42790/gdal-and-python-how-to-get-coordinates-for-all-cells-having-a-specific-value -- then I'd think you'd combine it with ZoomWithCenter from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53622/qgis-zoom-from-python-console