# Automatically include model into another model in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, workflow

I created a model (`model_final`) that calls another model (`model_first_step`). So to run `model_final`, I need to also have the `model_first_step`. You can find [both models and the workflow here for download](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/461322/88814), but the question should be understandable without this context.

How can I include the `model_first_step` into the `model_final`? Of course, I could copy the whole workflow inside `model_first_step` into `model_final`, but doing it manually would be cumbersome. Is there a way to automatize this, so I don't have to share two files (two models)?

*The model on the right is called inside the model on the left:*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model designer you can find all models as an expandable list in the algorithm tab.
You might have to scroll down.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Maybe worth expanding the answer a bit. But probably indeed this is the easiest way to achieve that.