# Handling QgsVectorLayer?

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to start with PyQGIS and make a simple script in the processing toolbox.

`##theVector=vector
 theVec = processing.getObject(theVector)
 features = theVec.getFeatures()`

now, if I'd like to iterate over every Object I'd write:

`for feature in features:`

but I just want to get the first object, and NOT interate over everyone..
I have tried:

```
f1 = features.get(1)
```

and get

> 'QgsFeatureIterator' object has no attribute 'get' See log for more details

How do I get just one feature?

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Comment: ad documentation: check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/where-to-find-qgis-tutorials-and-web-resources

Comment: Thank you underdark, I will check that and keep your advise about the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pure Python problem not limited to PyQGIS.  I learn Python before using PyQGIS and the Help of PyQGIS.

In pure Python examine the attributes of `feature` with the [dir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) function:

```
dir(features)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'close', 'isClosed', 'next', 'nextFeature', 'rewind']
```

And there is no `get` here, hence the error: `QgsFeatureIterator' object has no attribute 'get' See log for more details` when you try `f1 = features.get(1)`.

In contrats, `features` has the `__iter__` method  which means that you can use a `for loop`, look at [Understanding Python Iterables and Iterators](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/understanding-python-iterables-and.html)

> When Python executes the for loop, it first invokes the **iter**() method of the container to get the iterator of the container. It then repeatedly calls the next() method (**next**() method in Python 3.x) of the iterator until the iterator raises a StopIteration exception. Once the exception is raised, the for loop ends.
>    (when Python executes the for loop, it first invokes the **iter**() method of the container to get the iterator of the container)

So `for feature in features` is the same as `features.next(), features.next(),...`

Therefore the answer of Underdark `features.next()` is a pure Python problem, not limited to the Help of PyQGIS (The same kind of problem existed with Avenue, even with the Help)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach to get the first feature would be:

```
>>> f1 = features.next()
```

When you type `help (features)` you'll get the help:

`Help on QgsFeatureIterator in module qgis._core object:
class QgsFeatureIterator(sip.wrapper)
 |  QgsFeatureIterator()
 |  QgsFeatureIterator(QgsFeatureIterator)
 | 
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      QgsFeatureIterator
 |      sip.wrapper
 |      sip.simplewrapper
 |      __builtin__.object
 | 
 |  Methods defined here:
 | 
 |  __iter__(...)
 |      x.__iter__() <==> iter(x)
 | 
 |  close(...)
 |      QgsFeatureIterator.close() -> bool
 | 
 |  isClosed(...)
 |      QgsFeatureIterator.isClosed() -> bool
 | 
 |  next(...)
 |      x.next() -> the next value, or raise StopIteration
 | 
 |  nextFeature(...)
 |      QgsFeatureIterator.nextFeature(QgsFeature) -> bool
 | 
 |  rewind(...)
 |      QgsFeatureIterator.rewind() -> bool`