# QGIS: new install, but 8 icons to choose from. Which to use?

Tags: qgis

A very naive and basic question.  I have just downloaded QGIS 2.14.0 and now have 8 new & related icons on my desktop.  As a student with no practical GIS work experience, I have worked with ArcGIS 10, and now for it's proclaimed benefits would like to learn to drive QGIS, but am a little confused over which of the choices is appropriate.  Also, is one of these icons a similar application to ENVI?

I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: As someone new to QGIS it may be worth you reviewing http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/where-to-find-qgis-tutorials-and-web-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with the icon labelled `QGIS Desktop 2.14.0`. You will be learning about the other icons by time (if you need them at all).

I have added this icon to my taskbar to have easy access. The others I have moved into a new Desktop folder named `GIS`.

If you double-click on a QGIS project file, QGIS will automatically be started.

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I've done and am now slowly working through the training manual which is, so far, been excellent.