# Getting Started With QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I am a fairly strong user of ArcGIS, having started with version 8 long ago. But I'm looking for an inexpensive alternative right now for a client, and I want to investigate QGIS as a possible solution.

Thing is, I have never touched it before. I see mention of Grass databases and OSGEO4W shells and Python. I don't know what *any* of that means. No clue.

So where can I find a beginner's guide to QGIS, that more or less walks a newbie through the various components, how they work, why they're needed, and gets me to the point that I can import a .gdb and make some sample maps and queries to show my client?

Comment: Take a look through the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/index.html). Although it mentions QGIS 2.8, most of it still applies to the latest QGIS version (2.14). Also, you can find more links from this post: [Where to find QGIS tutorials and web resources?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/where-to-find-qgis-tutorials-and-web-resources).