# Learning to use QGIS online?

Tags: qgis, references

I want to start using QGIS. I have worked in ArcGIS but I would like to start learning QGIS online.

Any suggestions for good online courses (hopefully free or not very expensive)?

Comment: Related: [Seeking QGIS tutorials and web resources?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/seeking-qgis-tutorials-and-web-resources)

Answer (score 1):

**Start with the old long-term release version, QGIS 2.18.** There are many free tutorials and resources for this version. There's a list available here: [Seeking QGIS tutorials and web resources?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/seeking-qgis-tutorials-and-web-resources)

The current long-term release version (3.4) came out very recently, so there aren't as many tutorials available. **Upgrade to 3.4 once you feel comfortable with the basic functions of QGIS.**

**Minor versions of QGIS come out every few months, but stick to the long-term release versions because the new versions are always buggy.** When you're just learning it's very hard to tell the difference between a bug and user error.